# "Execute as" in stored procedure doesn't apply to "OPENROWSET"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to open xlsx file in stored procedure. When I'm executing procedure in schema app, but with execute as dbo:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [app].[Compare] (
    @p_CPN_ID int,
    @p_FILE_LOCATION nvarchar(max)
)
WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DELETE FROM dbo.IMPORT

        DECLARE @v_OPEN_ROWSET NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @v_OPEN_ROWSET = 'INSERT INTO dbo.IMPORT
        SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=' + @p_FILE_LOCATION + ''',''select * from [Arkusz1$]'')'

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString = @v_OPEN_ROWSET

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       declare @err nvarchar(max)
       set @err = ERROR_MESSAGE()
       RAISERROR(@err,16,1)
       RETURN 1
    END CATCH
END
```

I'm getting this error:

> Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted.

but procedure in dbo schema without "execute as dbo" works perfectly fine. Why?

Comment: The `dbo` has unlimited permissions within the database itself. Yet, you are not trying to access data within the database nor data in the SQL server. So, permissions on the SQL server are of no relevance. The person who wishes to execute the above must have permissions outside the SQL server (even if the file is on the same machine / physical computer) to access `@p_FILE_LOCATION`. The `dbo` is a system account only know to the SQL server but not outside to Windows. But Windows (!) is the one handling the permissions to `@p_FILE_LOCATION`.

Comment: In short: Windows (possibly active directory) must trust SQL and the SQL account must have the proper permissions outside of SQL within the Windows file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolve. First, I created user "app" in Windows Server and granted rights to folder with files. Next create new "app" credentials in ssms and map to "app" login. Then I had to modified procedure:

```
EXECUTE AS CALLER
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString = @v_OPEN_ROWSET
REVERT
```